# PHP pagination not working as intended

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have an smsdashboard with a searchbox, when you type the a name it takes the name to another page and queries the database and return results.

How do I paginate those results.

Here is my testing environment, check it out: 
http://www.bojelongprimary.co.za/smsdashboard.php?id=Difile&type=Educator

please make sure the send by search radio button is clicked

Comment: If you don't post your code , how can we find out ?

Comment: I have a problem in my code. How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact sql query depends on what type of SQL server you have used.

For example in MySQL you can paginate by LIMIT and OFFSET at the end of a query.

SELECT something
FROM table
LIMIT 20, 40

It says that you get 20 records from 40. position.